# Words for "non-religious" that are broader than "secular"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say "it's very *something* of a bookstore/cafe/whathaveyou to be open on Christmas day." Neither *secular* nor *pluralist* feels quite right. *secular* excludes people who are religious, rather than being inclusive of both religious and non-religious people. The sense I'm hoping to convey is that while most people in the US do take the day off, there's something welcoming about not assuming that everyone wants the day off.

I'm looking for a word that conveys a sense of being *welcoming* or *open-minded* and compatible with lots of different perspectives.

I've been looking through thesauruses for synonyms and antonyms to secular, welcoming, pluralist, open-minded, pragmatic, and partisan. Still, I'm not coming up with what I want. I feel like there's a specific word that I can't zero in on. *pluralist* comes closest, I guess, but it isn't quite right.

**Note:** I edited the question to address some of the questions in the comments: I am (was) looking for a word that suggests that the actor isn't assuming that everyone shares the same religion or celebrates religious holidays. I can see how I could have explained that better.

Comment: This is a great question because it is asking to fill an obvious lexical gap for the US culture. But it may be somewhat broad (implicitly) since there could be many practical solutions to it, ie trying to be literal 'non-Christian' (which may be too confrontational if 'secular' is), 'holiday-oblivious', 'always open/365 days of the year', etc. 'Multireligious'? 'Secular' does do what you want though.

Comment: open minded of them

Comment: I am afraid it is still not clear what you do mean by this this staying open on Christmas Day.  It depends on what it is you are talking about.  It is very necessary for the hospital to stay open on Christmas Day.  It is very common for Uber cars to operate on that day, and gas stations on the on the interstates.  Many restaurants open on Christmas day  (at least in the UK they do, as do bars and public houses.  So you must be talking about retail shops or stores   and shopping malls.  Frankly, if these were to open, the word I would use would be 'hopeful' or 'optimistic'.

Comment: Would it be possible to choose a different example? These days, in the US, there are all sorts of reasons why a business might be open on Christmas day, and some of those reasons have nothing to do with being open-minded. A movie theater is not open in order to accommodate non-Christians.  Most of the movie-goers around here *are* Christians. Thus, the theater is open so that they can earn money.  *Edit*: ah, I see @Tuffy agrees.

Comment: Why do you feel that *secular* suggests **opposition** to religion? *Secular* is not synonymous with *atheist*. (It is true, though, that *secular* cannot be simply plugged into the sentence, because 'very secular of somebody' would sound awkward.) Edit: ah, I see @RosieF agrees.

Comment: "secular suggests opposition to religion". Goodness me, I hope it doesn't. Chambers, after listing the senses relating to long time-periods, defines **secular** as "pertaining to the present world, or to things not spiritual; civil, not ecclesiastical; lay, not concerned with religion". Nothing about *opposing* religion there. It's bad enough having to denote certain views or practices by having to settle for an adjective which says they're not a particular other thing. Being misunderstood as *opposing* that other thing would be worse.

Comment: . . . ermm ... the shop is open in order to make money. I doubt there is a deeper ideological motivation for working on what is normally a holiday. _It's very commercial of them to be open on Christmas Day._

Comment: “It's very **helpful/useful/kind** of them to remain open on Christmas Day” Is there a reason why none of these adjectives in bold are suitable? One buzzword that's been doing its rounds is **inclusive**, I see the OP also uses it in their question.

Comment: Certainly most alternatives to secular are far more anti-religious. https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/secular

Comment: **Ecumenical!** @Mitch's use of "multireligious" took me to a new set of thesaurus searches on multi-faith and inter-faith and I found it. I'm going to go ahead and accept a good answer, because I appreciate that folks tried.

Comment: While *ecumenical* would be an apt term in its original Greek meaning (what concerns the whole inhabited world), in contemporary English, it is usually understood to stand for something that involves unity or neutrality among different **Christian** churches. It is thus not an apt term for accommodating non-Christians.

Comment: I’ve never considered “secular” to have much of a negative or anti-religious connotation.

Comment: @GrahamH. Did you see the note at the end? Secular implies non-religious, rather than a more expansive term for people who have a different faith or are not religous

Comment: @Amanda Yes, I don’t deny that secular may not be the best word for the concept you’re trying to denote. I’m sorry I don’t have a better one. I just find your statement “secular suggests opposition to religion” to be disagreeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is very [**accommodating**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/accommodating) of them to be open on Christmas Day.

This avoids any religious connotations, but implies they might like to be closed.

> adjective
>
> Willing to fit in with someone's wishes or needs.
>   *We always found our local branch most accommodating.*

Comment: Realized that what I was actually looking for was **ecumenical** which I think of as "not favoring one faith over another" but most of Miriam Webster's definitions address branches of Christianity specifically, so it is probably not the right word, except in the more general definition, "Concerned with establishing or promoting unity among churches or religions."

Comment: That isn't a word which is used in an everyday way.

Comment: @Amanda, even according to the more general definition, it would not be an apt term for accommodating those who are not religious at all.

Answer (score 2):

"*It's very **inclusive** of the bookstore/cafe to be open on Christmas day*", perhaps.

> '***inclusive***' - Not excluding any person on the grounds of race, gender, religion, age, disability, etc.; encouraging or accommodating participation from all sections of society (OED)

Answer (score 1):

The shop is open in order to make money. I doubt there is a deeper ideological motivation for working on what is normally a holiday. It's very **commercial** of them to be open on Christmas Day.

> occupied with or engaged in commerce or work intended for commerce

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commercial)

[Unless you are talking about a Homeless Shelter being open on Christmas Day in which case I would say it is very **charitable** of them.]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the word to have an opposition of religion then

**progressive** *might* do the trick.

Definition of progressive (Entry 1 of 2)
1a: of, relating to, or characterized by progress
b: making use of or interested in new ideas, findings, or opportunities

or otherwise

**nonconforming** but it denotes no relation to religion.

Definition of nonconforming
: not in accordance or agreement with prevailing norms, standards, or customs : not conforming

taken from https://www.merriam-webster.com/

Answer (score 0):

"Agnostic" comes to mind but I don't know about the shop-opening hours. I would keep the shop open whenever it paid off. But, hey, I'm an agnostic, so maybe I'm not the right person to ask.